# mvc 5 asp.net Webgrid I dont want my gridview to show the records when quatity is zero

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webgrid, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an issue with an webgrid

I have a table Produit with its model, controller and view

I have a webgrid that shows all the records on the table Produit

and it works fine my code is for the model

```
 public class Produit
{
    public int ProduitID { get; set; }
    public string ProduitNom { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Qte { get; set; }
    public string CheminImage { get; set; }
    public decimal PrixUnitaire { get; set; }
    public int CategorieID { get; set; }




}
```

my code is for the view is

```
@{
 var monGrid = new WebGrid(source: Model, rowsPerPage: 4, columnNames: new[]    { "Produit-Nom", "PrixUnitaire", "Description", "Qte" });}

@monGrid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "webgrid-table",
                headerStyle: "webgrid-header",
                footerStyle: "webgrid-footer",
                alternatingRowStyle: "webgrid-alternating-row",
                selectedRowStyle: "webgrid-selected-row",
                rowStyle: "webgrid-row-style",
                columns: monGrid.Columns(
                monGrid.Column("ProduitId", header: "Sélectionner", format:   (item) => item.GetSelectLink("= > ")),
                monGrid.Column(columnName: "ProduitNom", header: "Nom"),
                monGrid.Column(columnName: "Description"),
                monGrid.Column(columnName: "Qte"),
                monGrid.Column(columnName: "Ajouter", format: (item) =>   Html.ActionLink("Vers achats", "ValeurChoisies", new { id = item.ProduitId }))

   ));
```

it shows all the records but now I just want to show only the records where the quantity of the product is greater than zero

I tried to do a query on the controller and pass it on the return statments but didnt work

this is what I tried

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {


      return View(db.Produits.Where(q => q.Qte > 0).Select(p => new { p.ProduitNom, p.Description, p.Qte }).ToList());
    }
```

however it didnt work .....any ideas please would be really appreciate it

Comment: this should be functionally equivalent, but try separating out the Linq Query and check that it actually is returning the results you expect.

Comment: Why pass an anonymous object? Just use `return View(db.Produits.Where(q => q.Qte > 0);`

Comment: Stephen Thank you very much it worked like a charm! I Dont know why I try to over complicate things!